# mvc redirect action link to a specific view with id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.actionlink

I have a controller named (**Term1score**) and inside the controller i have two different action method(**Index_Test,EditScore**).

Now inside the view of my (**Index_Test**)i have Html action-link that will redirect to (**Edit Score**)now what i want is it will redirect to the specific Id (**Example if(Index_Test) SubjectId=1 then it will go to(EditScore) SubjectID=1**,)as u can see in my Controller they both target same SubjectID,any idea on how to fix this? thanks and appreciate your response..

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index_Test(int? id)
    {
        List<Term1Score> score = db.Term1Scores.Where(x => x.SubjectID == id).ToList();
        return View(score);
    }



    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditScore(int? id)
    {
        List<Term1Score> score = db.Term1Scores.Where(x => x.SubjectID== id).ToList();
        return View(score);
    }
```

I have tried to put this inside the Index_Test View.
This One Work but it will always go to Id 1 only-How to make this automatic changed?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", "Term1Score", new { id= "1" }, null
```

I have tried few but still nothing.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", "Term1Score", new { id=@Model.id }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", "Term1Score", new { testId=testId.id  }, null)
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", "Term1Score", new { id= "" }, null)
```

Comment: Redirect is not the right terminology. A redirect is when a server receieves a request to one URL and then sends a response indicating the request should be sent again to a different URL. What you are trying to create is a hyperlink to a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : As per the comment

> i'm targeting one link to edit all now with the code u gave its
>   looping one by one, and Editscore is a Multi editable table

In this case, You can get the first item and use it's `SubjectID`

```
@model List<Term1Score>
@{
    var id = Model.FirstOrDefault() != null ? Model.First().SubjectId : (int?) null;
}

@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", "Home", new { id = id }, null)
```

Another option is create a view model which has 2 properties, one for the Id and one for the List of Term1Score and use that to transfer data to your view.

---

Your `Index_Test` action method is passing a list of Term1Score objects to the view, So you need to loop through them and render a edit link

The `EditScore`  action method parameter name is `id`. So make sure when you are building the anchor tag using Html.ActionLink helper, you use `id` as the route value object key.

So in your `Index_Test.cshtml`

```
@model List<Term1Score>
@foreach (var testId in Model)
{
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditScore", "Home", new { id = testId.Id }, null)    
    </p>
}
```

Also , in the `EditScore` method, you probably want to edit a single record, Currently you are returning the same collection as the previous method. You probably want to get the single record matching that id.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult EditScore(int id)
{
   Term1Score score = db.Term1Scores.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id== id);
   if(score==null)
   {
      return Content(" This item does not exist"); // or a view with the message
   }
   return View(score);
}
```

Now since you are passing a single item, make sure your view is strongly typed to that

```
@model Term1Score
<h2>@Model.Id</h2>
```

Comment: I dont want this to loop over and over

Comment: What you mean, you do not want loop over and over ? Your view is strongly typed to a collection. Don't you want to show an edit link for each items in the collection ?

Comment: i'm wrong hehe sorry can i add this bellow on my first Loop in the view? cos i already have this loop(@foreach (var item in Model)<tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Subjects.SubjectName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScoreName)
        </td>

Comment: yes, you can add the call to the Html.ActionLink in the loop

Comment: Bro i'm targeting one link to edit all now with the code u gave its looping one  by one, and  Editscore is a Multi editable table

Comment: I see. So you need to pass the same id you used in the GET action to the second action method. See the update i made to the answer.

Comment: Oh yes It work bro, haha thank u so much u are my angel haha damn i'm so happy i wanna hug u and buy u a drink haha thank so much man it actually work now my table can be edit based on ID,and multi editing works so smooth haha..